# I need Help to take a photo on Phonegap (Android) and send it to php (SERVER)

Tags: cordova

my problem is that i need to take a photo and send it to php(server) but i try with differents codes and i dont have the expected response

```
function startCamera() {

            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
                quality: 50,    
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
            }); 
            function onSuccess(imageData){    

                alert(imageData);
                var url = "http://www.trueware.mx/eduardo/mybiometrics_online/foto.php?callback=parseRequest&foto="+imageData;
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.setAttribute('src', url);
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            }
            function onFail(message) 
            {    
                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }
        }
        function parseRequest(response)
        {
            try
            {
                console.log(response);
                for (var i=0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var dato = response[i].foto;
                        alert(dato);
                        var foto=Base64.decode(response[i].foto);
                         var imagen = document.createElement('img');
                         imagen.setAttribute('src',foto);
                         document.getElementById('cabezera').appendChild(imagen);
                }
            }
            catch(an_exception)
            {
                document.write("Error de Conexion");
            }
        }
```

So i need help and an example for do it.

the part of javascript and the part of php

If somebody can to help me i will be gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Zac Vineyard has a good blog post doing exactly what you want:

http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/